# Stacked or Grouped bar Chart in R and Python

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a huge set of data which I want to plot either in R or in python as a Stacked or Grouped bar chart. Let's assume this is my data

```
df<- data.frame(Continent= c("Asia","Africa","EU","US","Antractica"),
                Death= c(24242,75457,63521,967445,947),
                Cases= c(92332,338753,700346,8536856,4232) )
```

In all examples that I've seen about these bars, there are always two categories and one value ( like the well known diamond or car built in data set in R) but it's not the case for me. I have a `strings` value (*Continent*) and then a bunch of columns as `dbl`

the code bellow gives me kinda the result but I'm not satisfied

```
p<- ggplot(df)+ aes (x=Continent, y= Cases, fill= "Cases" ) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(y=Death, fill= "Death")) + ylab("All Covid Cases")
p
```

[image: R created plot]

which is okay kinda but the legend is not quite right (seeing *fill* instead of *legend*) and also I couldn't  convert it to grouped one by giving the `postion="dodge"` value!
I've also tried Seaborn but neither of those get me the following pictures.
and I want to get this kinda of the plots
[image: grouped one] or the
[image: stacked]

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Hi! Was your question answered? If so, please accept an answer so that future users can refer to it easily.

Answer (score 1):

In R, general idea is to get data in long format so that it is easy to plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= c(Death, Cases)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Continent, y= value, fill= name) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]
OR

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= c(Death, Cases)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Continent, y= value, fill= name) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your dataframe from wide to long. The issue you were having was that stacked or grouped charts cannot be colored by numbers, they need a category to distinguish them.

When we `melt` your dataframe using the `data.table` package, it goes from looking like this:

```
    Continent  Death   Cases
1:       Asia  24242   92332
2:     Africa  75457  338753
3:         EU  63521  700346
4:         US 967445 8536856
5: Antractica    947    4232
```

To looking like this:

```
    Continent variable   value
 1:       Asia    Death   24242
 2:     Africa    Death   75457
 3:         EU    Death   63521
 4:         US    Death  967445
 5: Antractica    Death     947
 6:       Asia    Cases   92332
 7:     Africa    Cases  338753
 8:         EU    Cases  700346
 9:         US    Cases 8536856
10: Antractica    Cases    4232
```

After this, we can plot easily.

Here is the complete code:

```
library(data.table)
#Define Dataset
df<- data.frame(Continent= c("Asia","Africa","EU","US","Antractica"),
                Death= c(24242,75457,63521,967445,947),
                Cases= c(92332,338753,700346,8536856,4232) )

# We will combine the counts into one column, and distinguish them by 
# Type in another column
df <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c("Continent"),measure.vars = c("Death", "Cases"))

#Lets Plot
ggplot(df, aes(factor(Continent), value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  labs(title = "Cases and Deaths by Continent", x = "Continent", y = "Number", fill = "Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually all you need is `barplot` which comes with R. No need to touch the data.

```
barplot(cbind(Death, Cases) ~ Continent, df, col=c("lightblue", "orange"),
        legend.text=names(df)[2:3])
```

[image]

```
barplot(cbind(Cases, Death) ~ Continent, df, col=c("orange", "lightblue"), beside=T,
        legend.text=names(df)[3:2])
```

[image]